# How to run the first flutter demo app without assembledebug error

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I'm using windows 10 operating system and I've successfully installed Flutter and Android studio. When I try `flutter run` it throws the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/gradle/launcher/cli/DefaultCommandLineActionFactory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

`flutter doctor` says everything is fine. Someone please help me fix it !!

Comment: where are you located?

Comment: I'm from India.

Comment: Use IP change software.

Comment: Do you mean VPN

Comment: yes vpn.........

Comment: What does vpn have to do with Flutter project which is completely offline?